# Update Android Play store Developer information

Tags: android, google-play

I like to update all the information in the addition information section in the play store mainly the developer section- it display the  web site link and email address. I have login to the google play console and under setting - developer account but different information is displayed.

> Is there a different section that I need to update?

Comment: please check [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139626?hl=en) link First Point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can change the Email Address but can not remove:**

1. Sign in to your [Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/)
2. Click All applications
3. On the left menu, click **Store presence** > **Store listing**
4. At the bottom of the page, type your contact email address or website. **A contact email address is required to publish or update apps on Google Play.**
5. Your contact email address doesn't have to be the same account you use to sign in to your developer account. Save your changes.

I have provided link of [Official Document](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139626?hl=en)